# JQuery Range Slider

Tags: jquery, slider, range

Hi I'm all new to JQuery i found a slider here: [JQuery Range Slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range), I copied this code in my html page

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      values: [ 75, 300 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "€" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - €" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
      " - €" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
  });
 $( "input" ).rangeslider();
  </script>
```

I also included the css an the slider div in my body.
If I move the slider for example from $ 10 - $ 30 it should show in my content only these products, which are between this range. The Price is in an input field.

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

Get range value using  $("#amount").val() and then make your request to get required response with this value.

In the main slide function do as follows

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );

        //here make ajax call with input value 1 as ui.values[ 0 ] 
        //                                and  2 as ui.values[ 1 ] 
}
```

Comment: My Question ist that my Prices are input fields and when I move the slider the content should only show the products which match the price range - but it won't work?!

Comment: your description is not that clear...I am updating the given answer